# What's the difference between encoding and charset? cp1252 and windows1252

Tags: windows-1252, cp1252

What's the difference between encoding charset cp1252 and windows1252?
or are they the same?

Comment: That https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 starts with _"Windows-1252 or CP-1252 (code page – 1252) is a 1 byte character encoding of the Latin alphabet"_ wasn't enough of a clue for you, or did you not even make it that far ...?

Comment: Thanks, I did do a google search but I guess since I did windows1252 and cp1252 without the -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Some APIs require you to call it windows-1252 and other APIs require you to call it CP1252. I've heard a few others as well but they are just aliases. Somebody took umbrage at MS just deciding they were the sole authority on code page identifications.